# Concatenate arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, concatenation

Can you somehow concatenate two arraylists to a third?
I know you can do it when you have  (as below):

```
ArrayList<String>arraylist1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String>arraylist2 = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String>al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.addAll(arraylist1);
    al.addAll(arraylist2);
```

But how do you do it if you have arraylists in different constructors like?:

```
ArrayList<People>arraylist1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Billing>arraylist2 =new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: why would you even consider adding tose two probably completly different classes into one `List`?

Comment: Adding ArrayLists of different types is a bad idea. Of course, you can add them all to an ArrayList of Objects (raw) but that's not a good thing

Comment: ok, then I better stop wasting time on trying to solve this. Haha. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: But if I have a constructor with people and a constructor with billings and i wanna print out the right billing to the right person.... any ideas?

Comment: @JJ72 use a `Map` instead. using a `List` would just make everything way more difficult. As an alternative you could also just reference a `List` of `Billing` in a single `People` instance, and/or reference a specific `People` instance in a single `Billing` instance.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really guess I will have to learn more about maps, can't avoid them anymore...

Comment: Make sure to close this question with an accepted answer. You can type your own answer if you want.

Answer (score 4):

The method `addAll` of `Collection<E>` has signature

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

The wildcard here (`?`) means that it is general enough to accept any collection of any subtype of `E`.

This means that if the element type of your third list is of a common supertype of the types of the two original lists (`Object` will always work) you can do it.

For example this prints `[X, Y, 1, 2, 3]`.

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("X", "Y");
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Object> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
list3.addAll(list1);
list3.addAll(list2);
System.out.println(list3);
```

However it is generally best to try to avoid using collections of mixed type in this way.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you guys have an alternative solution to my basic problem (printing the right people with the right billing), please let me know :)

Comment: @JJ72 Are the people and billing lists the same length? If so perhaps you need a new class with fields `person` and `billing`?

Comment: @JJ72 as proposed in my comment, you could create references from `Billing` to `Person` and/or vica verse, or create a seperate class `Billingbook` which holds something like a  `Map<Person,List<Billing>>` where you can get your information from.

Comment: @JJ72 It looks like you asked an XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Sounds like Kevin Esche is right though.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. Lets say you have the person with name, dateofbirth, phonenumber and adress. while billing has companyName and adress. But I will really consider your idea. I'm just trying to learn, so I can be flexible, haha.